# Geo distance Search MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation, coordinates, spatial

I'm doing a geo search with mysql using the spatial extension. FOr that i did a stored procedure (thats work really well when i tri on command line in mysql like that

> mysql> CALL
>   test2(GeomFromText('POINT(-0.93961472
>   43.52843475)'),0.6 );

```
DROP PROCEDURE `test2`//
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test2`(IN center2 point,IN dist int)
BEGIN
SET @center = center2;
SET @radius = dist;

SET @bbox = CONCAT('POLYGON((', 
 X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, ',', 
 X(@center) + @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, ',', 
 X(@center) + @radius, ' ', Y(@center) + @radius, ',', 
 X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) + @radius, ',', 
 X(@center) - @radius, ' ', Y(@center) - @radius, '))' 
);

SELECT professionnels.*, AsText(coord) 
FROM professionnels 
WHERE Intersects( coord, GeomFromText(@bbox) ) 
AND SQRT(POW( ABS( X(coord) - X(@center)), 2) + POW( ABS(Y(coord) - Y(@center)), 2 )) < @radius limit 20;
end
```

But the problem is that i need to call that from php. and when i do it, an error is return said that

> PROCEDURE test2 can't return a result
>   set in the given context

So.. How can i use a turn around to return a set of data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the last part into

```
/*delete all rows from temp_table*/
DELETE FROM temp_table WHERE temp_table.somefield is not null;

INSERT INTO temp_table
  SELECT professionnels.*, AsText(coord) 
  FROM professionnels 
  WHERE Intersects( coord, GeomFromText(@bbox) ) 
  AND SQRT(POW( ABS( X(coord) - X(@center)), 2) 
      + POW( ABS(Y(coord) - Y(@center)), 2 )) < @radius limit 20;
```

Then you can select from the temp_table and find resultset there.

Comment: Yeah but what if there is more than one user doing the search ??
this search is actually a  function that allow the user to search some POI around a city so it will be callaed by lot of user... i can't use that method... it wont work

Comment: Ok.. I have used the driver MYSQLI instead of MYSQL and it works. I can retreive the dataset that the stored procedure return.

But is this a good idea? 

Thanks

Comment: @Fazoulete, it's a hack, but if you use a temporary table, each session will have it's own table so the users will not see each others results. If you get the resultset straight out of the SP that's better though.